# Capture SEE (Server-Sent Events) in Azure

Tags: azure, signalr, server-sent-events, azure-eventhub

I am having trouble to identify the best "tool" to solve the problem. I am using a python library which publishes to its data via Sever-Sent-Events (SSE) (see https://github.com/wattsight/wapi-python/blob/development/wapi/events.py).

I would like to constantly listen for new events. However, I am not sure which tool in Azure in appropriate. An Azure Function would have to run continously which seems like a misuse, SignalR requires control over the "sender" of events and I don't know if EventHub would be able to manage that job.

Thank you for letting my learn from your experience.

Comment: The SSE emitter doesn’t need to run continuously.

Comment: Ok, but my problem is receiving the events, not sending them.

Comment: Why you just use EventBus?

Comment: @Iammy, do you still have any other concerns? If the answer is helpful, could you please help accept it as answer? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The azure Eventhub is the right service to receive new events. Besides that, it can also provide other benefits like scalability, events storage etc.

And you can also consider using [azure function with eventhub trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-hubs-trigger?tabs=csharp). But it has a limitation about the incoming message max size.